# Dynamic Code that applies a code row by row in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

Excel Sheet

[image]

I have the following code that corresponds to one row in the sheet. My Question is how to write this such that it continuously applies the code row by row until we reach the last row? Then, how would I write a dynamic code where if I added new rows, it recognizes to apply the code to those new lines.

For context what this code does is that it takes a user input, subtracts that value from March until either there is no more user input to subtract or if march has a value of 0. If march is 0 and we haven't subtracted all of the user input we move on to February and do the same thing, and so on until we reach January.

```
Sub variance_sub()

    Dim reduce As Double, c As Range, diff As Double

    reduce = InputBox("what is the Variance required? (Pressure use a positive number)")

    Set c = ActiveSheet.Range("T7") 'march cell



    If reduce = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No further action required"
    ElseIf reduce > 0 Then      'This is for a pressure'
        Do
            If c.Value >= reduce Then
                c.Value = c.Value - reduce
                reduce = 0
            Else
                diff = reduce - c.Value
                c.Value = 0
                reduce = diff
            End If
            If c.Column > 1 Then Set c = c.Offset(0, -1) 'move left if we can
        Loop While reduce > 0 And c.Column >= 18
    Else
        c.Value = c.Value + reduce
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't realize there was an accept button. It's been done

Comment: Thanks. So instead of just T7 you want T8 etc? If so basically you just need to wrap all that in a loop which runs through T7:T?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
Sub variance_sub()

    Dim reduce As Double, c As Range, diff As Double, rng As Range

    reduce = InputBox("what is the Variance required? (Pressure use a positive number)")
    'get range to process
    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range("T7:T" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "T").End(xlUp).Row) 'march cell
    End With

    'loop through range
    For Each c In rng.Cells   

        If reduce = 0 Then
            Debug.Print "No further action required" 'probably don't want msgbox
        ElseIf reduce > 0 Then      'This is for a pressure'
            Do
                If c.Value >= reduce Then
                    c.Value = c.Value - reduce
                    reduce = 0
                Else
                    diff = reduce - c.Value
                    c.Value = 0
                    reduce = diff
                End If
                If c.Column > 1 Then Set c = c.Offset(0, -1) 'move left if we can
            Loop While reduce > 0 And c.Column >= 18
        Else
            c.Value = c.Value + reduce
        End If

    Next c 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up creating the following just because there are some nuance in the spreadsheet not shown in the screenshot.

 Numrows = Range("C7", Range("C7").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 2 'Cant be new rows in black added" otherwise this will get messed up'
    MsgBox Numrows
    For x = 0 To Numrows
    reduce = InputBox("what is the Variance required? (Pressure use a positive number)")

    Set c = ActiveSheet.Cells(7 + x, 20) 'march cell

Comment: some rows are highlighted a certain colour in which the formula cannot be applied to, but I would like to try myself how to incorporate that condition before asking.